# Excel Indirect alternatives

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that I am trying to reference another sheet that is shared via OneDrive. Opening both files on the computer, creating a local reference, will properly create the link via onedrive/sharepoint. Closing the docs has no effect on the ability to get the updated data.

However, I am trying to automate this process. The final product will have 10-11 unique ranges across multiple sheets, and that process duplicated across 30-40 documents. That would be a lot of tedious work.

All the source sheets have the same structure and thus the data that needs pulled is gotten through the same coordinates.

I would like to be able to have the share link pasted in a cell, and have the spreadsheet dynamically read the link, create the references, and dynamically update. I am attempting to do this without using VBA, as some users will only access the file via excel for web.

note: using excel for business

Attempted to use INDIRECT function to reference shared link (same that manually will link content), but it results in REF error.
Can successfully create the references needed, but requires manually opening every file, and selecting ranges.

I also tried to simplify the reference process by using VBA on the source sheets by clicking a button to select the range desired, but when referencing from the other sheet, the macro does not trigger.

Comment: As you're experiencing, `INDIRECT` doesn't work with closed workbooks. There are some workarounds. If you're going the VBA route, then please create a [reprex].